# Loadtesting with visual studio copying and pasting different than inserting a new request

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Looking at the xml file in the raw that is created from a web performance test (the .webtest file) one sees that each Get request has a guid attached to it. The GUID is unique for each inserted request, even if the requests are the same. However, if one uses copy and paste the GUIDS are duplicated in the pasted request, even if one subsequently changes one of the URLs.

What is the significance of these guids? I would assume they are used as identifiers for tracking statistics about requests but have no solid evidence for that assumption, so maybe not. Does it matter if one uses copy paste and has duplicated GUIDs in get requests?

Maybe put differently, is this behavior of copy/paste a bug or a feature and what harm/benefit does it entail if GUIDs are duplicated across requests?

Answer (score 0):

I use copy and paste of web tests quite frequently and have not run into any trouble based on the GUID behavior described in your question.

AFAIK this is an implementation detail that should not be of concern to users of web tests.

Is there a reasong you where looking at the xml generated? Plain curiosity?

Comment: Because we have a lot of hand made test files in a different (internal) format and I was looking at how to reduce the burden of converting them by hand.

Comment: These internal tests that you mention, are they automated? If so, I suggest that you re-run them while fiddler is running. You can then take the fiddler trace and export is as a VS Web Test. Simply record the http requests using fiddler and then  go to File -> Export Sessions -> All Sessions -> VS Web Test. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/06/30/import-and-export-http-archives-from-fiddler.aspx and

Comment: Hello John, Did you look at my comments. Did my suggestion help? If so, could you mark it as an answerr?